# Prove that $\sum_{r=0}^k {{n}\choose{r}} < \frac{n^n}{k^k (n-k)^{n-k}}$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients

Let $n\ge1$ and $k<\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$
Prove that:
$$\sum_{r=0}^k {{n}\choose{r}} < \frac{n^n}{k^k (n-k)^{n-k}}$$

I know that (obvious):
$${{n}\choose{k}} < \frac{n^n}{k^k (n-k)^{n-k}}$$
and (can be proved by induction)
$$\sum_{r=0}^k {{n}\choose{r}} < \frac{n-k}{n-2k}{{n}\choose{k}}$$
But I don't understand how I can use this facts in order to prove first inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{r=0}^k {{n}\choose{r}} = 1+ \sum_{r=1}^k {{n}\choose{r}} \le k{{n}\choose{k}} < {{n}\choose{k}}^k = \frac{n^k}{k^k (n-k)^{k}} < \frac{n^n}{k^k (n-k)^{n-k}}$$

Comment: But when $n=1$ then $1+{{n}\choose{1}} > 1*{{n}\choose{1}}$

Comment: And how to prove that $1+k{{n}\choose{k}} < {{n}\choose{k}}^k$

Comment: @Ivan, In fact, $n$ could not be equal to 1, because then $k = 0$ and we have division by zero. $kx < x^k$ is true for any real variable $x\ge2$ and $k\ge1$.